# Asserting that a number is in binary

Tags: python, binary

Im working on my homework and encountered a problem. I had to string numbers in binary back to back.
Lets say we have joined(1, 3) - 1 is the starting number and 3 says that Im gonna work with 2 more numbers (if i had joined(5, 4), id work with 5, 6, 7 and 8)
1       1
2        10
3          11
result  11011

```
def num_to_2(number):
    num2 = 0
    exp = 0
    while number >= 1:
        num2 += (number % 2) * (10 ** exp)
        number = number // 2
        exp += 1
    return num2


def num_lenght(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    lenght = 0
    while number >= 1:
        number /= 10
        lenght += 1
    return lenght


def joined(start, count):
    result = 0
    end = start + count - 1
    for i in range(end, start - 1, -1):
        number = num_to_2(i)
        res_lenght = num_lenght(result)
        result += number * (10 ** res_lenght)
    return result


def main():
    assert joined(1, 3) == 0b11011
    assert joined(10, 4) == 0b1010101111001101
    assert joined(8, 5) == 0b10001001101010111100
    assert joined(99, 2) == 0b11000111100100
    assert joined(999, 3) == 0b111110011111111010001111101001
    assert joined(1111, 1) == 0b10001010111
```

The function works properly but it gives me results without the 0b prefix, which i need in order to pass the asserts. How do i add it there? and also: i cant use strings.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: i added the rest of my code so it makes more sense

Comment: Also -- the title of your question doesn't really make sense. `assert joined(1, 3) == 0b11011` is the same as `assert joined(1, 3) == 27` since `0b11011` *is* 27 (just expressed as a binary literal). A number is a number, irrespective of the base used to express it.

Comment: Can't use strings? Why not? You are joining sequences, strings is the natural choice.

Comment: @JohnColeman it was added, im sorry for that complication!

Comment: You are converting a binary number, like 5, ie 101 in binary, into the number 101, ie one hundred and one. That makes no sense. That's not how binary numbers work.

In binary, 5 is one zero one. Not one hundred and one. I think you, or your teacher, are confused about what binary is...

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah i understand the concept of number bases, im not a native speaker so i probably expressed myself a little badly

Comment: Are you sure that your assertions are right? Perhaps you want `assert joined(1, 3) == 11011`? Your functions seems to be strange functions which take a number and return another number whose base-10 literal only involves `0` and `1`.

Comment: @LennartRegebro its in my homework instructions, our professors dont want us to use strings. i already solved this problem it via stringsand they sent it back to me

Comment: This is what im supposed to do - convert numbers to binary, add them together back to back (which obviously creates a number that is different to actually doing a sum - thats the point of the homework) and pass the asserts

Comment: OK, and the assertions are as they instructed? Because for example 0b111110011111111010001111101001 is just a different way of writing 1048552425. Yes,  one billion, forty-eight million five hundred and fifty-two four hundred twenty five. But your result is 111110011111111010001111101001, which is hundred eleven octillion  hundred and ten septillion, etc. Very different numbers.

Comment: If you want to pass the assertions as written, you need an inverse to `num_to_2`.

Comment: There is obviously some misunderstanding here (or the homework instructions are absurd). Just to add to the confusion: My guess is that the professors are sane (dangerous assumption, I know...) and that the intention is to get the students to use bitwise and shift operators.

Comment: @LennartRegebro yes i understand that 11011 is a different number to 0b11011, thats exactly the problem that i have. i have a binari-ly written number that is actuall in 10 base. the only thing that really comes to mind is to create a new function to manually convert it.

Comment: Note that *numbers* are not in binary, decimal, or any other base. Numbers just *are*. It is their *representations* (whether as strings or Python literals) that make use of base-N notation, for whatever base N you might want.

Comment: @PetraŠtěpánová I was confused of what they possibly could want you to learn from this exercise, so I did it. I still don't know, but I updated my answer anyway. John Colemans version is more clever though. Possibly too clever, they might not believe you though of that yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved my problem, what i had to do was "manually" convert the pseudo-binary number into base 10 number. this is my code now:

```
def convert_to_2(number):
    num2 = 0
    exp = 0
    while number >= 1:
        num2 += (number % 2) * (10 ** exp)
        number = number // 2
        exp += 1
    return num2


def num_lenght(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    lenght = 0
    while number >= 1:
        number /= 10
        lenght += 1
    return lenght


def joined(start, count):
    result = 0
    end = start + count - 1
    for i in range(end, start - 1, -1):
        number = convert_to_2(i)
        res_lenght = num_lenght(result)
        result += number * (10 ** res_lenght)
    result = convert_to_10(result)
    return result


def convert_to_10(number):
    num10 = 0
    exp = 0
    while number >= 1:
        num10 += (number % 10) * (2 ** exp)
        number = number // 10
        exp += 1
    return num10


def main():
    assert joined(1, 3) == 0b11011
    assert joined(10, 4) == 0b1010101111001101
    assert joined(8, 5) == 0b10001001101010111100
    assert joined(99, 2) == 0b11000111100100
    assert joined(999, 3) == 0b111110011111111010001111101001
    assert joined(1111, 1) == 0b10001010111


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

thank you so much for your help(:

Comment: It is always good when you can solve your own problem Congratulations. By using bitshift operations, it is possible to solve the problem without introducing pseudo-binary numbers (see my answer below). If your professor has introduced bitwise operators, that might have been the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's unclear what your teachers mean with "don't use strings". I found this a very strange homework, so I did it, without strings.

I'm not sure what you are supposed to learn from it, but here it is:

```
def to_binary(number):
    b = 0
    while number >= 2**(b+1):
        b += 1
        
    while True:
        if number >= 2**b:
            yield 1
            number -= 2**b
        else:
            yield 0
        b -= 1
        if b < 0:
            return


def joined(start, count):
    result = 0
    for i in range(start, start + count):
        for digit in to_binary(i):
            result = (result << 1) + digit
    return result
    

def main():
    assert joined(1, 3) == 0b11011
    assert joined(10, 4) == 0b1010101111001101
    assert joined(8, 5) == 0b10001001101010111100
    assert joined(99, 2) == 0b11000111100100
    assert joined(999, 3) == 0b111110011111111010001111101001
    assert joined(1111, 1) == 0b10001010111
```

It implements a `to_binary()` function that will yield a sequence of integers. Then the join function will binary shift the result to the left, and add that one or zero.

No strings attached...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit-shifting version which passes all assertions:

```
from math import ceil, log2
from functools import reduce

def join2(a,b):
    n = ceil(log2(b+1))
    return (a<<n) | b

def joined(start, count):
    return reduce(join2,range(start,start+count))

def main():
    assert joined(1, 3) == 0b11011
    assert joined(10, 4) == 0b1010101111001101
    assert joined(8, 5) == 0b10001001101010111100
    assert joined(99, 2) == 0b11000111100100
    assert joined(999, 3) == 0b111110011111111010001111101001
    assert joined(1111, 1) == 0b10001010111
```

Comment: Oh, that's pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about the `0b` prefix, it is merely a way to express numeric literals in Python source code.  They could have written `27` or `0x1b` instead of `0b11011` but the binary form makes it clearer what bit pattern is expected in the integer value returned by joined().

You can use the integer's .bit_length() method to know how many bits are used to represent a number.  This should make the function a bit simpler.

```
def joined(start,count):
    result = 0
    for n in range(start,start+count):
        result <<= n.bit_length()       # offset by the number of bits
        result  |= n                    # add the number's bits
    return result
```

if you're not allowed to use that method, you can write your own function to do it:

```
def bitLength(N): return 0 if not N else bitLength(N//2)+1
```

If you're also not allowed to use bit-wise operators, you can do it with multiplications and additions:

```
def joined(start,count):
    result = 0
    for n in range(start,start+count):
        result  *= 2**bitLength(n)      # offset by the number of bits
        result  += n                    # add the number's bits
    return result
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the `bit_length` method. Simpler than using `log2` (and probably more reliable for larger ints).